# mixing database and object query in linq and provide paged results

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I need to build a query that provides paged results. Part of filtering occurs in the database and part of it occurs in objects that are in memory.

Below is a simplified sample that shows what I could do i.e. run a linq query against the database and then further filter it using the custom code and then use skip/take for paging but this would be very inefficient as it needs to load all items that match the first part of my query.

```
    Things.Where(e=>e.field1==1 && e.field2>1).ToList()
            .Where(e=>Helper.MyFilter(e,param1,param2)).Skip(m*pageSize).Take(pageSize);
```

MyFilter function uses additional data that is not located in the database and it is run with additional parameters (paramX in the above example)

Is there a preferred way to handle this situation without loading the initial result fully in memory.

Answer (score 1):

yes, query and page at the database level. whatever logic is in Helper.MyFilter needs to be in the sql query.

the other option, which is more intrusive to your code base. is to save the view model, as well as the domain entity when the entity changes. part of the view model would contain the result of `Helper.MyFilter(e)` so you can quickly and efficiently query for it.

Comment: Your first option is not possible because MyFilter function uses some additional information that is not in the db. Saving the result of MyFilter is not viable as Myfilter actually has additional parameters. I've updated the question accordingly.

Comment: if your saving the result of MyFilter in the db then it doesn't matter how it's calculated, only that it is. but you are saving it when the entity is altered, not when you are querying the database.

Comment: if you have requirements outside of the database then there is no way to page the results in the database, therefore the results must be loaded into memory before paging.

Comment: It has to be loaded in memory for sure but is it not possible to load only parts of it? I was thinking of loading pages of db filtered data, applying secondary in-memory filter and continue getting more data from the database if the result is less than my actual page size. This is OK for the first page but gets tricky after that.

Answer (score 1):

To support Jason's answer above - entity framework supports .Skip().Take().  So send it all down to the db level and convert your where into something EF can consume.

If your where helper is complicated use Albahari's predicate builder:

http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx

or the slightly easier to use Universal Predicate Builder:

http://petemontgomery.wordpress.com/2011/02/10/a-universal-predicatebuilder/ based on the above.

Answer (score 0):

```
.ToList()
```

You are converting your query into a memory object i.e. list and thus causing the query to execute and then you provide the paging on the data.

You can put it all in one `Where` clause:

```
Things.Where(e=>e.field1==1 && e.field2>1
            && e=>Helper.MyFilter(e)).Skip(m*pageSize).Take(pageSize);
```

and then `.ToList()`.
That way you will give Linq to Sql a chance to generate a query and get you only the data that you want.

Or there is a particular reason why you want to do just that - converting to a memory object and then filtering? Although I don't see the point. You should be able to filter out the results that you don't want in the Linq to Sql query before you actually execute it against the database.

**EDIT**

As I can see from the discussion you have several options.

If you have a lot of data and do more reads than writes it might be wise to save the results from `Helper.MyFilter` into the database on insert if it's possible. That way you can increase performance on select as you will not pull all the data from the database and also you will have a more filtered data on the `SELECT` itself.

Or you can take another approach. You can put `Helper` class in a separate assembly and [reference that assembly from SQL Server](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/Managed_Code_in_SQL.aspx). This will enable you to put the paging logic in your database and use your code as well.

Comment: this assumes the logic in `Helper.MyFitler(e)` can be translated to sql.

Comment: As Jason mentioned this won't work as the function includes code that cannot be translated in to SQL. That's why I used ToList

Comment: @cellik - Do you have to do everything in the exact order? I was thinking maybe you could "partially optimize" the query with reordering things: .Where(e=>e.field1==1 && e.field2>1).Skip(m*pageSize).Take(pageSize)            .Where(e=>Helper.MyFilter(e))

Comment: If I do that, the number of items I get might be less than my page size since I apply additional filter after Take